# How to add log to custom file in cakephp app?

Tags: php, logging, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to log a webhook response to a custom log file custom.log which is saved on config/logs/custom.log path. I can easily log the webhook to the debug.log file in the same directory by

```
Log::debug('my desired logs)
```

How can I log the same log in the custom.log file. Thank you

Comment: Did you check https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Configure logs/custom.log to receive all levels, but only
// those with `custom` scope.
Log::config('custom', [
    'className' => 'File',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'levels' => [],
    'scopes' => ['custom'],
    'file' => 'custom.log',
]);

Log::debug('this gets written only to custom.log', ['scope' => ['custom']]);
```